PowerShell: trying to make file readonly made it disappear
I've tried to make a directory ReadOnly in PowerShell, yet it disappeared instead.
How can I get it back to appear in the Explorer?
PS C:\Users\jaboja> cd .\Documents\
PS C:\Users\jaboja\Documents> (Get-Item Nextcloud).Attributes
ReadOnly, System, Directory, Archive, ReparsePoint
PS C:\Users\jaboja\Documents> (Get-Item Nextcloud).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
PS C:\Users\jaboja\Documents> (Get-Item Nextcloud).Attributes
Get-Item : Could not find item C:\Users\jaboja\Documents\Nextcloud.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Item Nextcloud).Attributes
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\jaboja\Documents\Nextcloud:String) [Get-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand


It seems it can be recovered by adding -Force to Get-Item, and substracting the ReadOnly:
(Get-Item Nextcloud -Force).Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'

And the cause was adding a ReadOnly to an already ReadOnly directory, resulting in invalid attributes value, which caused it to disappear from directory listing.

In general, MS ignores the RO attribute for folders.
